# Cancelling socket related all IO calls

Tags: c++, winsock2

I am doing coding for windows OS in C++ and I am using socket version 2.

Is there any C++ APIs available to cancel  socket related all IO calls for the current thread?

Comment: Are you directly listening sockets with recv in one of your own threads or are you using something like ``WSAAsyncSelect`` with message loop to let Windows notify you when something happens.

Comment: @unlut - I am directly directly listening sockets with recv

Comment: @Alex once close the socket whether the recv() returns immediately?

Comment: Look at [`CancelIo/Ex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/cancelio). You can pass a Winsock `SOCKET` to it, if the `SOCKET` has been created to enable Overlapped I/O. `socket()` creates overlapped sockets, as does `WSASocket()` when the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag is used. You can use `WSARecv()` instead of `recv()` to perform an overlapped I/O read.